# About pythagorean triples

Tags: diophantine-equations, euclidean-geometry

In the circle of diameter $AB$ it is well known each point $C$ determines a right triangle $\Delta ABC$  and so it is with every point $D$ on the circle of diameter $AC$ determining a right triangle $\Delta ACD$.

[image]

1) Are there points $C$ and $D$ such that $(AB, BC, CA)$ and  $(AC, CD, DA)$  be pythagorean triples and the triangles $\Delta ABC$  and $\Delta ACD$ being of equal area?.

2) Assuming $BC = CD$, prove that the possibility that both $(AB, BC, CA)$ and  $(AC, CD, DA)$  are pythagorean triples depends  on the parity of $BC$, possible in one case and impossible in the other.

Comment: Where is this from? What have you tried?

Comment: 1) is by a desire to know; 2) is by studying concerned diophantine equations.